# how to derive Kolmogorov distribution $K_\alpha$ for big n?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

The [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) rejects the null hypothesis  at level $\alpha$ if $$\sqrt{n}D_n>K_\alpha$$

where $$D_n=\sup_x |{F}_n(x)-F(x)| $$, and

$$\operatorname{Pr}(K\leq K_\alpha)=1-\alpha$$ 
, where $K$ follows Kolmogorov distribution.

There are tables for $K_\alpha$, but [this website](http://www.real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/kolmogorov-smirnov-table/) gives formula for $K_\alpha$ for big $n$.

For example, it says, if $n$ is over 50, $$K_{\alpha=0.01} = 1.63 $$ $$K_{\alpha=0.05} = 1.63$$ $$K_{\alpha=0.01} = 1.36$$ $$K_{\alpha=0.1} = 1.22 $$  $$K_{\alpha=0.15} = 1.14 $$ $$K_{\alpha=0.2} = 1.07 $$

How could such number be reached?

Comment: Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution):

$$Pr(K\leq x)=1-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} e^{-2k^2 x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{x}\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-(2k-1)^2\pi^2/(8x^2)}$$

and refers to [Marsaglia G, Tsang WW, Wang J (2003). "Evaluating Kolmogorov’s Distribution". Journal of Statistical Software 8 (18)](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i18/paper). For another proof, see e.g. Theorem 2 in [these lecture notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture14.pdf).

Comment: @Dougal thanks.. i found the line in the first paper "... the mean and standard deviation of Dn are, roughly, .8687/√n and .26/√n ..."